# How do i balance the sequence so i have the equal amount on the left and right?

Tags: python

this is the problem that i am trying to solve. Help would be much appreicated. Thank you in advance

[image: Problem]

this is what i've done so far

```
N=int(input()
i=0
r=0
balance=[]
balance1=0
balance2=0
while i<N:
    number=int(input())
    balance.append(number)
    i=i+1

i=0
if (N%2 ==0):
    while (i<=N/2):
        balance1=balance1 + balance[i]
    i=i+1
    while (i<=N):
        balance2=balance2 + balance[2]

if (balance1==balance2):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Comment: is the picture visible now?

Comment: Yes it is. It would be greatly aprpeciated if you were to break your code into parts and explain what each part does and where you are struggling instead of giving us the whole code alone. This seems like a homework question and doing your homework is not the scope of stackoverflow. Helping you if you are struggling is however.

Answer (score 0):

The first part (to get the list of numbers) can be written more simply as:

```
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

A quick way to check the "balanced-ness" of the list for a given index is to `sum` the slices before and after the given index, e.g.:

```
>>> numbers
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
>>> sum(numbers[:2]), sum(numbers[2:])
(2, 4)
>>> sum(numbers[:3]), sum(numbers[3:])
(3, 3)
>>> sum(numbers[:4]), sum(numbers[4:])
(5, 1)
```

So all we need to do is check the equality of those two slices for all indices in the list -- if `any` of them are equal, we have our answer.

```
>>> any(sum(numbers[:i]) == sum(numbers[i:]) for i in range(len(numbers)))
True
```

making our whole program simply:

```
numbers = [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]
if any(sum(numbers[:i]) == sum(numbers[i:]) for i in range(len(numbers))):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

This could be optimized slightly by replacing `any` with a loop which checks the sums and breaks early once the right-hand slice exceeds the left-hand slice (since then no solution can exist).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the indexes and check if the sum of the right part is equal to sum of the left part

Remark: you should start at 1 and not 0 since `input_list[:0] == []`

```py
from typing import List

def is_balanced(input_list: List[int]) -> bool:

   for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
      if sum(input_list[:i]) == sum(input_list[i:]):
         return True

   return False
```

Then you can use the function as follows:

```py
N = int(input())

input_list = [int(input()) for _ in range(N)]

if is_balanced(input_list):
   print("Yes")
else:
   print("No")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code with the minimal amount of editing to your code:

```
def balancing():
    N=int(input())
    i=0
    r=0
    balance = []
    
    balance1=0
    balance2=0
    while i<N:
        number=int(input())
        balance.append(number)
        i=i+1

    i=0

    while balance1 < sum(balance)/2:
        balance1=balance1 + balance[i]
        i=i+1
        
    while (i<=N-1):
        balance2=balance2 + balance[i]
        i+=1
            
    if (balance1==balance2):
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print("No")
```

While dividing the list in two seems like a good idea, it doesn't work for some inputs. You should use sum to see if the values have already reached half of the total sum.

**Instead of checking if the index reached half:**

```
while (i<=N/2):
```

**Check if the sum so far as reached half of the total sum:**

```
while balance1 < sum(balance)/2:
```